# networkx - read edgelist in chunks (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I've got a very large network to be read and analyse in Networkx (around 500 million lines), stored in a gzip weighted edgelist (Node1 Node2 Weight). So far I try to read it with:

```
# Open and Read File
with gzip.open(network,'rb') as fh:
    # Read Weighted Edge List
    G = nx.read_weighted_edgelist(fh, create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

but since it is very large I have some memory issues. I wonder whether there is a way to read the file in "pandas" style along chunks with fixed length. Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

This is a small extraction of my edgelist file (Node1 Node2 Weight):

```
30879005 5242 11
44608582 2295986 4
24935102 737450 1
42230925 1801294 1
20926179 2332390 1
40959246 1100438 1
3291058 3226104 1
23192021 5818064 1
16328715 7695005 1
11561383 2102983 1
1886716 1378893 2
23192021 5818065 1
2060097 2060091 1
7176482 3222203 2
46586813 1599030 1
35151866 35151866 1
12420680 1364416 5
612044 92878 1
16260783 3373725 1
26475759 85310 1
21149725 17011789 1
1312990 105320 1
23898296 1633222 3
3635610 2103011 1
12737940 4114680 1
18210502 10816500 1
45999903 45999903 1
8689446 1977413 1
5998987 3453478 3
```

Comment: Can you post a few lines of what your edge list looks like, I've loaded NX graphs from dfs before

Comment: Thanks, just added some info to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the data in as a csv into a pandas df:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_edge_list, sep='\s+', header=None, names=['Node1','Node2','Weight'])
```

Now create a nx DiGraph and perform a list comprehension to generate a list of tuples with (node1, node2, weight) as the data:

```
In [150]:

import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from([tuple(x) for x in df.values])
G.edges()
Out[150]:
[(16328715, 7695005),
 (42230925, 1801294),
 (40959246, 1100438),
 (12737940, 4114680),
 (3635610, 2103011),
 (16260783, 3373725),
 (45999903, 45999903),
 (7176482, 3222203),
 (8689446, 1977413),
 (11561383, 2102983),
 (21149725, 17011789),
 (18210502, 10816500),
 (3291058, 3226104),
 (23898296, 1633222),
 (46586813, 1599030),
 (2060097, 2060091),
 (5998987, 3453478),
 (44608582, 2295986),
 (12420680, 1364416),
 (612044, 92878),
 (30879005, 5242),
 (23192021, 5818064),
 (23192021, 5818065),
 (1312990, 105320),
 (20926179, 2332390),
 (26475759, 85310),
 (24935102, 737450),
 (35151866, 35151866),
 (1886716, 1378893)]
```

Proof we have weight attributes:

```
In [153]:

G.get_edge_data(30879005,5242)
Out[153]:
{'weight': 11}
```

To read the edge list in chunks set the `chunksize` param in `read_csv` and add the edges and weights using the above code for each chunk.

**EDIT**

So to read in chunks you can do this:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()
for d in pd.read_csv(path_to_edge_list,sep='\s+', header=None, names=['Node1', 'Node2', 'Weight'], chunksize=10000):
    G.add_weighted_edges_from([tuple(x) for x in d.values])
```

Comment: No worries, I just tidied my code up, you can just perform a list comprehension on `df.values` no need to select the columns

Comment: Should I use the `pd.concat` to concatenate chunks in the network or only:
`for chunk in iter_csv:
 G.add_weighted_edges_from([tuple(x) for x in chunk.values])`
where `iter_csv = pd.read_csv(path,chunksize=n)`

Comment: You can probably avoid that as what you want is to add just the edges to your network so define your graph outside the code that reads the edge list, the df created by each call to `read_csv` can be re-used to keep the memory overhead low

Comment: ok so, following your code and adding the chunks, I'm just running 
`for i in df:
     G.add_weighted_edges_from([tuple(x) for x in i.values])`

Comment: Sorry for bothering but I'm still experiencing high memory consumption despite the chunksize method. May you add a sample code of how to add the edges for each chunk? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @fblamanna I've added updated code, if you're still experiencing problems it could be that NX is not very memory efficient in the graph creation which to be honest is not surprising, you may have to consider doing some kind of normalisation or bucketing of the nodes

Comment: Thanks a lot Ed, again. Yes I know that is not very memory efficient, that's why I was looking for something smarter (pandas) to help it a bit! Thanks!