# AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'from_pandas_dataframe'

Tags: pandas, networkx

I have `networkx v. 2.1`. to make it work w/ pandas dataframe, i tried following:

- installed via `pip3`, this did not work generated `Atrribute Error` as in title, hence uninstalled.
- re-installed with '`python3 setup.py install`"

Error description.

> AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'from_pandas_dataframe`

Steps to reproduce Error:

I imported data using `csv`. I did this because I just wanted to read only 5000 rows from the dataset.

```
x=pd.DataFrame([x for x in rawData[:5000]])

x[:10] 

0   1   2
0   228055  231908  1
1   228056  228899  1
2   228050  230029  1
3   228059  230564  1
4   228059  230548  1
5   70175   70227   1
6   89370   236886  1
7   89371   247658  1
8   89371   249558  1
9   89371   175997  1

g_data=G=nx.from_pandas_dataframe(x)

module 'networkx' has no attribute 'from_pandas_dataframe'
```

I know I am missing the `from_pandas_dataframe` but cant find a way to install it.

```
[m for m in nx.__dir__() if 'pandas' in m] 

['from_pandas_adjacency',
 'to_pandas_adjacency',
 'from_pandas_edgelist',
 'to_pandas_edgelist']
```

Answer (score 83):

In networkx 2.0 `from_pandas_dataframe` [has been removed](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/release/release_2.0.html).

Instead you can use [`from_pandas_edgelist`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html?highlight=from_pandas_edgelist#networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist).

Then you'll have:

```
g_data=G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(x, 1, 2, edge_attr=True)
```

Comment: I was using `pip install networkx` but only got 1.11 which do not have `from_pandas_edgelist`, then I tried `pip install --upgrade networkx`, finally got `from_pandas_edgelist`

Comment: How about undirected graph?

Answer (score 14):

A simple graph:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Build a dataframe with 4 connections
df = pd.DataFrame({'from': \['A', 'B', 'C', 'A'\], 'to': \['D', 'A', 'E', 'C'\]})

# Build your graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'from', 'to')

# Plot it
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score -5):

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29102744/networkx-read-edgelist-in-chunks-pandas) helps as well:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from([tuple(x) for x in x.values])
nx.info(G)


'Name: \nType: DiGraph\nNumber of nodes: 5713\nNumber of edges: 5000\nAverage in degree:   0.8752\nAverage out degree:   0.8752'
```

Comment: that doesn't concerns the answer