# Python: best way to create a network?

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have a dataframe containing the information of transactions between two companies

```
df    
      idA   idB   amount  nameA  nameB
0      4     5     300     xxx    yyy
1      3     7     150     kkk    uuu 
2      3     6     289     kkk    vvv
3      1     4     189     hhh    iii
```

I want to create a network using the the `networkx` package.

```
G=nx.Graph()
for i in df.index:
    G.add_node(df['idA'][i], name = df['nameA'][i])
    G.add_node(df['idB'][i], name = df['nameB'][i])
    G.add_edge(df['idA'][i], df['idB'][i], weight = df['amount'][i] )
```

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the answer is yes. Just take a look at this documentation: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html

In your case I'd do:

```
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'idA', 'idB', ['amount'])
```

In case you'd add some other attribute to the nodes, follow this documentation: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_node_attributes.html

EDIT:
I'm sorry but I didn't noticed that from networkx 2.0 `from_pandas_dataframe` has been removed. Many thanks to @tohv that answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49223057/attributeerror-module-networkx-has-no-attribute-from-pandas-dataframe)

Finally, as I commented down, these are optimized functions. If we compare their speed in performing the same function of a for loop, the difference is consistent.

```
from random import randint
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
from time import time
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = [randint(0, 100) for _ in range(10000)]
df['b'] = [randint(0, 100) for _ in range(10000)]

c = 0
runs = []
while c <= 100:
    G=nx.Graph()
    start = time()
    for i in df.index:
        G.add_node(df['a'][i], name = df['a'][i])
        G.add_node(df['b'][i], name = df['b'][i])
        G.add_edge(df['a'][i], df['b'][i])

    run = time() - start
    runs.append(run)
    c += 1

print ('done in:', np.mean(runs), 'seconds')
```

done in: 0.6191224154859486 seconds

```
c = 0
runs = []
while c <= 100:
    G=nx.Graph()
    start = time()
    G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'a', 'b')
    run = time() - start
    runs.append(run)
    c += 1

print ('done in:', np.mean(runs), 'seconds')
```

done in: 0.014413160852866598 seconds

Comment: the problem is that the loop is more efficient than that function for large graphs

Comment: are you sure? Normally, these functions are optimized and, especially for large graphs, are preferable to simple loops...